# Does using '/' as a seperator in sementic URLs always require absolute paths

Tags: html, url, mod-rewrite

We are new to mod_rewrite and semantic URLs and despite researching Google and SO we have not been able to find a clear answer to this question.

When we use a forward slash as a seperator in our .htaccess, all of our image, css and js references in our html have to be rewritten from relative paths to absolute paths.

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ inhalt.php?ebene1=$1 [NC,L] # process ebene1
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)\/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ inhalt.php?ebene1=$1&ebene2=$2 [NC,L] # process ebene1,2
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)\/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)\/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ inhalt.php?ebene1=$1&ebene2=$2&ebene3=$3 [NC,L] # process ebene1,2,3
```

means having to rewrite:

```
<link href="css/acssfile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ajsfile.js"></script>
<img src="imgs/animage file.gif" alt="" />
```

to:

```
<link href="http://www.oursite.com/css/acssfile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.oursite.com/js/ajsfile.js"></script>
<img src="http://www.oursite.com/imgs/animage file.gif" alt="" />
```

Is this always a consequence of using forward slashes as seperators in semantic URLs, or is there a way to keep our relative paths?

Comment: _“Is this always a consequence of using forward slashes as seperators in semantic URLs”_ – it is a “consequence” of how resolving relative URLs works …

Comment: Of course you _could_ try to counter this by rewriting requests for resources that can’t be found internally as well – but this would mean extra work for the server, and it would also “break” caching if the same file was referenced from within multiple different “virtual” directories or depths … so referencing to the domain root using `/` is the easiest way to go. (And if keeping this “dynamic”, so that the whole project could be moved to a sub-directory at will is a concern, then using a constant for the base path and prefix every relative URL with that server-side would be the way to go.)

Answer (score 3):

The browser is resolving those CSS includes relative to the URL it's on. If your URLs change from `inhalt.php` to `foobar/`, then the browser is now in a different path. While it was on `/inhalt.php`, the relative path `css/acssfile.css` resolves to `/css/acssfile.css`. However, when it's on `/foobar/`, that relative path resolves to `/foobar/css/acssfile.css`.

It's a good idea to use absolute paths, but not absolute URLs including the domain. So, link to your asset files as:

```
<link href="/css/acssfile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer! For some reason using <link href="/css/acssfile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> makes the css file unreachable.

Comment: @Richard As long as you're on the domain `www.oursite.com`, there should be no difference between `href="http://www.oursite.com/css/acssfile.css"` and `href="/css/acssfile.css"`.

Comment: And does this mean that as standard ALL semantic URLs using forward slashes have to absolute paths or is there a mod_rewrite solution to this?

Comment: @Richard There's no "have to". It's simply a matter of using relative paths vs. absolute paths, which is a relevant decision whether you use mod_rewrite or not. Absolute paths are typically preferred, since relative paths can be fragile to work with (as you experience).

Answer (score 0):

You could probably keep your paths to resources relative to the root of your site : `/css/acssfile.css`, that way you don't have to care about the path of the actual page being displayed...